# Qmake can't find configuration file

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake, yocto

I built yocto image with meta-qt5.Image has been built successfully.But When I select qmake from Tools->Options->Build&Run->Qt Version in Qt creator I receive the following error:

> Could not read qmake configuration file /home/yusuf/yocto/poky/bananaProHf/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/home/yusuf/yocto/poky/bananaProHf/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/linux-oe-g++/qmake.conf.

It seems that Qt searches the "qmake configuration file" in a wrong directory level. The correct target directory for this search should have been:
 "/home/yusuf/yocto/poky/bananaProHf/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/linux-oe-g++/qmake.conf." 
Somehow it seems QT duplicates the "yusuf/yocto/poky/bananaProHf/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux" part in the search address.
Any ideas about this weird behaviour?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile the SDK toolchain for Qt Creator instead of just using the `qmake.conf` in Yocto.

Use `bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5` to compile the SDK, install it.
You will find `qmake` in a directory similar to this one. `/opt/poky/1.6.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/qt5/qmake`

For information on how to set up Qt Creator.  There is a Wiki [HERE](http://wiki.hioproject.org/index.php?title=HIO_Wiki:Set_Up_Qt_Creator_for_Yocto_Device)

Comment: Thans for your reply.But now I am getting following error while Qt is  compiling any appllication:"make: c: Command not found
make: [main.o] Error 127 (ignored)
make: c: Command not found
make: [mainwindow.o] Error 127 (ignored)" How can solve this problem?